# in C# (int) decimal and Convert.Int32(decimal) give me two different results

Tags: c#

I understand that there are rounding errors but can anyone explain why I get such different results using these different methods:

```
decimal amount = 9.990M;
var cost = Convert.ToInt32(amount*1000);
var cost1 = (int) amount*1000;
```

I get:

```
cost = 9990
cost1 = 9000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one should be

```
var cost1 = (int)(amount * 1000);
```

You have to multiply with 1000 and then convert the result. In your example you are converting first and then multiplying.

See **[Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(VS.71).aspx)**

Answer (score 15):

Try `(int)(amount*1000)`. In the `Convert`, the brackets enforce the precedence, but cast `(int)` takes precedence over the multiply - so you current have: `((int)amount)*1000`, which rounds (during the cast) to 9.

In particular, see "7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity" in the MS spec, which defines cast ahead of multiplication:

- 7.5: Primary:    x.y  f(x)  a[x]  x++  x--  new typeof  default  checked  unchecked  delegate
- 7.6: Unary:  +  -  !  ~  ++x  --x  (T)x
- 7.7: Multiplicative: *  /  %
- etc

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if its [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) issue? Try this:

```
(int)(amount*1000);
```